# Python way to clone a git repository

Tags: python, git, module

Is there a Python way without using a subprocess to clone a git repository? I'm up for using any sort of modules you recommend.

Comment: gitpy, i guess it would be called

Comment: @SilentGhost: you mean *this* gitpy? http://github.com/vmalloc/gitpy from http://www.ryaari.com/blog/?p=9

Comment: Looks like there's GitPython (http://pypi.python.org/pypi/GitPython, http://gitorious.org/git-python) which I don't think has a clone method, but I'll bet you could add one... internally it's going to have to call `git clone` anyway though.

Comment: [Dulwich][1] is a pure-Python implementation of Git that does not fork at all. Be aware that it's still under development, so it may be buggy. [1]:http://samba.org/~jelmer/dulwich/

Answer (score 88, accepted):

There is [GitPython](https://gitpython.readthedocs.io/en/stable/). Haven’t heard of it before and internally, it relies on having the git executables somewhere; additionally, they might have plenty of bugs. But it could be worth a try.

How to [clone](https://gitpython.readthedocs.io/en/stable/reference.html#git.repo.base.Repo.clone):

```
import git  # pip install gitpython
git.Git("/your/directory/to/clone").clone("git://gitorious.org/git-python/mainline.git")
```

(It’s not nice and I don’t know if it is the supported way to do it, but it worked.)

Comment: It does. But it is a little convoluted.

Comment: Oh, my bad, I missed that possibility. Mike, just remember, internally this is just calling the git executable anyway; it's just managing it a little for you.

Comment: I looked at gitorious.. just overlooked the clone option since its not documented at all.. but I expected whatever i used to to some sort of process command.. this works thanks!

Comment: This module was really helpful, thank you. Can you help me how to pull the master branch of already cloned repo using this module

Comment: How to handle authentication if it has to run in an automated way ?

Comment: Yes, i used gitpython. The drawback is that it is not pure API. It is dependent on git binary ( mandatory) to be present. For Authentication, i used personal access token.

Answer (score 217):

Using [GitPython](https://github.com/gitpython-developers/GitPython) will give you a good python interface to Git.

For cloning a new repository you can use [clone_from](https://gitpython.readthedocs.io/en/stable/reference.html#git.repo.base.Repo.clone_from) function:

```
from git import Repo  # pip install gitpython

Repo.clone_from(git_url, repo_dir)
```

See the [GitPython Tutorial](https://gitpython.readthedocs.io/en/stable/tutorial.html) for examples on using the Repo object.

**Note:** GitPython requires git being installed on the system, and accessible via system's PATH.

Comment: How to handle authentication if it has to run in an automated way ?

Comment: You can provide the authentication in the git_url, depending on from where you clone the repo, you may need to put the username and password/pat in there. See here for [Github](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10054318/how-do-i-provide-a-username-and-password-when-running-git-clone-gitremote-git)

Comment: Could we get an example of `git_url` and `repo_dir`?

Comment: Any way to fetch if already clone?

Answer (score 30):

My solution is very simple and straight forward. It doesn't even need the manual entry of passphrase/password.

Here is my complete code:

```
import sys
import os

path  = "/path/to/store/your/cloned/project" 
clone = "git clone gitolite@<server_ip>:/your/project/name.git" 

os.system("sshpass -p your_password ssh user_name@your_localhost")
os.chdir(path) # Specifying the path where the cloned project needs to be copied
os.system(clone) # Cloning
```

Comment: Works great, however if you use other relative paths in your project, you may want to remember the true working directory ``os.getcwd()`` before changing it with ``os.chdir(...)`` and reset it back afterwards.

Comment: @Maximosaic this can be avoided by using `git clone <repo_url> <target_path>`. No need to use `chdir`

Comment: work only on linux and mac. not work on windows

Comment: In addition to the other potential caveats already mentioned, if you want to run a shell command (in that case git cli) better go if favour of subprocess over os as os.system will be depreceted, cheers

Comment: this won't work for cross-platform ie both linux and windows

Answer (score 19):

Here it is

```
import git  # pip install gitpython
git.Repo.clone_from("https://github.com/*****", "folderToSave")
```

I hope this helps you

Comment: Any way to fetch if already clone?

Answer (score 14):

Here's a way to print progress while cloning a repo with [GitPython](https://github.com/gitpython-developers/GitPython)

```
import time
import git  # pip install gitpython
from git import RemoteProgress

class CloneProgress(RemoteProgress):
    def update(self, op_code, cur_count, max_count=None, message=''):
        if message:
            print(message)

print('Cloning into %s' % git_root)
git.Repo.clone_from('https://github.com/your-repo', '/your/repo/dir', 
        branch='master', progress=CloneProgress())
```

Comment: Here are some guidelines for [How do I write a good answer?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).  This provided answer may be correct, but it could benefit from an explanation.  Code only answers are not considered "good" answers.  From [review](https://stackoverflow.com/review).

Comment: Any way to fetch if already clone?

Answer (score 13):

Github's [libgit2](https://libgit2.github.com/) binding, [pygit2](http://www.pygit2.org/repository.html) provides a one-liner cloning a remote directory:

```
clone_repository(url, path, 
    bare=False, repository=None, remote=None, checkout_branch=None, callbacks=None)
```

Comment: Would this require installing `libgit2` separately, or does it come bundled together with `pygit2`?

Answer (score 5):

You can use [dload](https://pypi.org/project/dload/)

```
import dload
dload.git_clone("https://github.com/some_repo.git")
```

---

```
pip install dload
```

Answer (score 4):

With Dulwich tip you should be able to do:

```
from dulwich.repo import Repo
Repo("/path/to/source").clone("/path/to/target")
```

This is still very basic - it copies across the objects and the refs, but it doesn't yet create the contents of the working tree if you create a non-bare repository.

Answer (score 4):

Pretty simple method is to just pass the creds in the url, can be slightly suspect though - use with caution.

```
import os

def getRepo(repo_url, login_object):
  '''
  Clones the passed repo to my staging dir
  '''

  path_append = r"stage\repo" # Can set this as an arg 
  os.chdir(path_append)

  repo_moddedURL = 'https://' + login_object['username'] + ':' + login_object['password'] + '@github.com/UserName/RepoName.git'
  os.system('git clone '+ repo_moddedURL)

  print('Cloned!')


if __name__ == '__main__':
    getRepo('https://github.com/UserName/RepoYouWant.git', {'username': 'userName', 'password': 'passWord'})
```

Answer (score 1):

This is the sample code for gitpull and gitpush using gitpython module.

```
import os.path
from git import *
import git, os, shutil
# create local Repo/Folder
UPLOAD_FOLDER = "LocalPath/Folder"
if not os.path.exists(UPLOAD_FOLDER):
  os.makedirs(UPLOAD_FOLDER)
  print(UPLOAD_FOLDER)
new_path = os.path.join(UPLOADFOLDER)
DIR_NAME = new_path
REMOTE_URL = "GitURL"  # if you already connected with server you dont need to give 
any credential
# REMOTE_URL looks "git@github.com:path of Repo"
# code for clone
class git_operation_clone():
  try:
    def __init__(self):
        self.DIR_NAME = DIR_NAME
        self.REMOTE_URL = REMOTE_URL

    def git_clone(self):

        if os.path.isdir(DIR_NAME):
            shutil.rmtree(DIR_NAME)
        os.mkdir(DIR_NAME)
        repo = git.Repo.init(DIR_NAME)
        origin = repo.create_remote('origin', REMOTE_URL)
        origin.fetch()
        origin.pull(origin.refs[0].remote_head)
  except Exception as e:
      print(str(e))
# code for push
class git_operation_push():
  def git_push_file(self):
    try:
        repo = Repo(DIR_NAME)
        commit_message = 'work in progress'
        # repo.index.add(u=True)
        repo.git.add('--all')
        repo.index.commit(commit_message)
        origin = repo.remote('origin')
        origin.push('master')
        repo.git.add(update=True)
        print("repo push succesfully")
    except Exception as e:
        print(str(e))
if __name__ == '__main__':
   a = git_operation_push()
   git_operation_push.git_push_file('')
   git_operation_clone()
   git_operation_clone.git_clone('')
```

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to clone a repo on windows is:

1. pip install clone
2. clone [REPO] [USERNAME]

Example: clone Wifi-Brute Cyber-Dioxide

You can execute it via shell command

import os
os.system("pip install clone")
os.system("clone SSH-Brute Cyber-Dioxide")

Answer (score -1):

We can use simple solution without any library.

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import os

destination_path  = "destination/path/where/project/to/be/cloned"
clone_command = "git clone https://your.git.servername/git-folder/repo-name.git" 

clone_with_path = clone_command  +" "+ destination_path
os.system(clone_with_path)
```

**Perk:** It will create a destination folder if it doesn't exist.