# How do I provide a username and password when running "git clone git@remote.git"?

Tags: git

I know how to include a username and password in an HTTPS [Git URL](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-clone#_git_urls) like this:

```
git clone https://username:password@host
```

But I'd like to know how to provide a username and password to an SSH remote like this:

```
git clone git@host.git
```

I've tried like this:

```
git clone username:password@git@host.git
git clone git@username:password@host.git
git clone git@host.git@username:password
```

But they haven't worked.

Comment: You can't.  The "git" before the "@" is already a username. From where did you get the repository URL (git@remote.get)? From where did you get the idea that you have to provide a different username and a password?

Comment: My repos URL is from heroku "git@heroku.com:zxy-helloworld.git". And I use emacs shell to clone and push. If the shell asks for password, emacs will hang. This is a known issue with emacs on Windows: https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/windows/Sub_002dprocesses.html#index-subprocesses_002c-hanging-when-reading-input-213

Comment: What if the username is an email? how do you type it?   https://myemail@gmail.com@example.com   ?

Comment: See [GitHub's instruction on _how_ to create a token and that why it's _better_ due to scoping and permissions](https://help.github.com/en/github/authenticating-to-github/creating-a-personal-access-token-for-the-command-line)

Comment: @Honey the question is not GitHub specific.

Comment: Why has this question started to receive new answers after a gap of more than six years?

Answer (score 1933, accepted):

Based on [Michael Scharf's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10054318/how-do-i-provide-a-username-and-password-when-running-git-clone-gitremote-git#comment45751054_10054470):

You can leave out the password, so that it won't be logged in your Bash history file:

```
git clone https://username@github.com/username/repository.git
```

It will prompt you for your password.

Alternatively, you may use:

```
git clone https://username:password@github.com/username/repository.git
```

This way worked for me from a GitHub repository.

Comment: it doesn't have to be the same by the way. If your colleague created the git repo and you are logging in as another account, they will not be the same.

Comment: It is not advisable to put the password in the URL for this file is saved on the .git/config . Is not safe, it is better to use ssh key

Comment: @Zephiro your advice is poor, unless you also tell people to use a strong passphrase on their private key. Otherwise, there is not much difference in having a cleartext password vs an unprotected private key on your hard drive.

Comment: @MrDuk no problem, escape it (as %40 iirc).

Comment: @Bassetassen Works fine for clone. Does not work for pull. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11506124/how-to-enter-command-with-password-for-git-pull

Comment: You can leave out the password: `git clone https://username@github.com/username/repository.git`. git will ask you and it will not be saved in .git/config nor in your bash history

Comment: you can also type 'space' at the beginning of the line so that linux won't store the command in history

Comment: this is especially useful for old `git` versions, who do not ask for both "username" and "password" when cloning a repo on a fresh machine

Comment: You can also add a space in front of the command. This way, it won't be stored in your bash history.

Comment: Not so easy if the password contains unusual characters.

Comment: second username was creating issues removing that worked for me:

```git clone https://username:password@github.com/repository.git```

Comment: How to use if my password contains '@' symbol

Comment: @AtulAgrawal See Benjamin Gruenbaum's comment

Comment: Another option I like is using and auth token instead of the username to get past any prompts
`git clone https://<token>@github.com/username/repository.git`

Comment: I had a situation where I was already logged on as another user.  I tried the second option of this answer, and it said "Authentication failed."  I merely tried it a second time, and it prompted me for the password and worked.  <shrug>

Comment: when I use this command on google colab, this error is received: fatal: could not read Password for 'https://username@github.com': No such device or address, and it does not ask me for password

Comment: Thanks a ton!  Works  well  for  PULL on bitbucket.org as well : git pull https://[user]:[password]@bitbucket.org/[bitbucket-account]/[project].git [branch]

Comment: I had many different special characters in the password, the percent encoding helped me to include the password as part of URL.
Reference: https://fabianlee.org/2016/09/07/git-calling-git-clone-using-password-with-special-character/

Comment: if you use the format ``git clone https://username:password@github.com/username/repository.git`` and the error message ``URL using bad / illegal format or missing URL`` appears, then this is probably a special character in your password, then use ``git clone https://username@github.com/username/repository.git`` to wait for prompt.

Comment: Why are you even mentioning the first unsecure method and why do you put it in the first place?

Comment: @Black, what is exactly unsecured? URLs are encrypted so username and password are secured.

Comment: @MaksimShamihulau, it will show in your "history" file with your password in clear text

Comment: `password` would be replaced with `private_token` with GitLab.

Comment: my password has @ as a special character , how do i deal with it?

Comment: For Docker users, if you need to use HTTPS during the build phase to pull your project, you can clear the bash history just after with the `history -c` command.

Comment: THE QUESTION IS NOT GITHUB SPECIFIC, and neither should be the answer.

Comment: This is now deprecated and Github recommends using Personal Tokens or SSH over this. https://github.blog/2020-12-15-token-authentication-requirements-for-git-operations/

Comment: This solution worked, I couldn't clone a github repo because my git configs had other credentials. cmd and SourceTree didn't work but using this command I was able to clone successfully.

Comment: Why, if the question is about SSH, you answer with an HTTPS solution? Is the solution possible for SSH? No? Then write it in your answer and, if you want, tell wahy.

Comment: Hello. How do i insert a password that containts @ ?

Comment: This should not be done on a shared server as the password will be stored in the git remote URL.

Comment: thanks bro worked for me, just needed to replace password with <personal access token> of github

Comment: Replace the @ symbol in your password with %40. Url encode any other special characters. Try https://www.urlencoder.io/ but I'd recommend only putting in the special character(s) and not your whole password. ;)

Answer (score 295):

The `user@host:path/to/repo` format tells Git to use ssh to log in to `host` with username `user`.  From [`git help clone`](http://schacon.github.com/git/git-clone.html):

> An alternative scp-like syntax may also be used with the ssh protocol:
>
> `[user@]host.xz:path/to/repo.git/`

The part before the `@` is the username, and the authentication method (password, public key, etc.) is determined by ssh, not Git.  Git has no way to pass a password to ssh, because ssh might not even use a password depending on the configuration of the remote server.

### Use `ssh-agent` to avoid typing passwords all the time

If you don't want to type your ssh password all the time, the typical solution is to [generate a public/private key pair](http://www.openbsd.org/cgi-bin/man.cgi?query=ssh-keygen&sektion=1), put the public key in your [`~/.ssh/authorized_keys` file](http://www.openbsd.org/cgi-bin/man.cgi?query=sshd&sektion=8) on the remote server, and load your private key into [`ssh-agent`](http://www.openbsd.org/cgi-bin/man.cgi?query=ssh-agent&sektion=1).  Also see [Configuring Git over SSH to login once](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1595848/712605), [GitHub's help page on ssh key passphrases](http://help.github.com/ssh-key-passphrases/), [gitolite's ssh documentation](http://sitaramc.github.com/gitolite/gl_ssh.html), and [Heroku's ssh keys documentation](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/keys).

### Choosing between multiple accounts at GitHub (or Heroku or...)

If you have multiple accounts at a place like GitHub or Heroku, you'll have multiple ssh keys (at least one per account).  To pick which account you want to log in as, you have to [tell ssh which private key to use](https://superuser.com/q/232373).

For example, suppose you had two GitHub accounts:  `foo` and `bar`.  Your ssh key for `foo` is `~/.ssh/foo_github_id` and your ssh key for `bar` is `~/.ssh/bar_github_id`.  You want to access `git@github.com:foo/foo.git` with your `foo` account and `git@github.com:bar/bar.git` with your `bar` account.  You would add the following to your `~/.ssh/config`:

```
Host gh-foo
    Hostname github.com
    User git
    IdentityFile ~/.ssh/foo_github_id
Host gh-bar
    Hostname github.com
    User git
    IdentityFile ~/.ssh/bar_github_id
```

You would then clone the two repositories as follows:

```
git clone gh-foo:foo/foo.git  # logs in with account foo
git clone gh-bar:bar/bar.git  # logs in with account bar
```

### Avoiding ssh altogether

Some services provide HTTP access as an alternative to ssh:

- GitHub:

  ```
  https://username:password@github.com/username/repository.git
  ```
- [Gitorious](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gitorious):

  ```
  https://username:password@gitorious.org/project/repository.git
  ```
- Heroku:  See [this support article](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/http-git).

***warning***:  Adding your password to the clone URL will cause Git to store your plaintext password in `.git/config`.  To securely store your password when using HTTP, use a credential helper.  For example:

```
git config --global credential.helper cache
git config --global credential.https://github.com.username foo
git clone https://github.com/foo/repository.git
```

The above will cause Git to ask for your password once every 15 minutes (by default).  See [`git help credentials`](http://git-scm.com/docs/gitcredentials) for details.

Comment: This is the best explanation of how git works with SSH. My understanding is that when you specify git@githost.com:path/to/repo.git, it effectively tells git that the user is git itself and that it should go grab your credentials (public key) from the ssh-agent for the Host "githost.com".

Comment: Brilliant, I've only one github but used since I have 2 emails for different projects in other repos, replacing git@github.com with the custom name which locates the relevant IdentityFile for the particular email works perfectly!

Answer (score 143):

Follow these arguments to replace with your special cases if they are creating an issue:

```
 !   #   $   &   '   (   )   *   +   ,   /   :   ;   =   ?   @   [   ]

%21 %23 %24 %26 %27 %28 %29 %2A %2B %2C %2F %3A %3B %3D %3F %40 %5B %5D
```

So for example:

Actual URL: `https://usern@me:p@ssword@git/reponame.git`

Solution URL to use: `https://usern%40me:p%40ssword@git/reponame.git`

Comment: Rather than fooling around with that, use this command: MYPASS=\`echo -n "$ORIGPASS" | jq -sRr @uri\`

Comment: This looks like an answer for a different question.

Answer (score 90):

In the comments of [Bassetassen's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10054470/1021259), [plosco mentioned](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10054318/how-do-i-provide-a-username-and-password-when-running-git-clone-gitremote-git/10054470#comment76059152_10054470) that you can use `git clone https://<token>@github.com/username/repository.git` to clone from GitHub at the very least. I thought I would expand on how to do that, in case anyone comes across this answer like I did while trying to automate some cloning.

GitHub has a [very handy](https://help.github.com/articles/git-automation-with-oauth-tokens/) guide on how to do this, but it doesn't cover what to do if you want to include it all in one line for automation purposes. It warns that **adding the token to the clone URL will store it in plaintext in** `.git/config`. This is obviously a security risk for almost every use case, but since I plan on deleting the repository and revoking the token when I'm done, I don't care.

### 1. Create a Token

GitHub has a [whole guide here](https://help.github.com/articles/creating-a-personal-access-token-for-the-command-line/) on how to get a token, but here's the TL;DR.

1. Go to *Settings > Developer Settings > Personal Access Tokens* ([here's a direct link](https://github.com/settings/tokens))
2. Click "Generate a New Token" and enter your password again. (h[ere's another direct link](https://github.com/settings/tokens/new))
3. Set a description/name for it, check the "repo" permission and hit the "Generate token" button at the bottom of the page.
4. Copy your new token **before you leave the page**

### 2. Clone the repository

The same as the command [plosco gave](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10054318/how-do-i-provide-a-username-and-password-when-running-git-clone-gitremote-git/10054470#comment76059152_10054470), `git clone https://<token>@github.com/<username>/<repository>.git`, just replace `<token>`, `<username>` and `<repository>` with whatever your information is.

If you want to clone it to a specific folder, just insert the folder address at the end like so: `git clone https://<token>@github.com/<username>/<repository.git> <folder>`, where `<folder>` is, you guessed it, the folder to clone it to! You can of course use `.`, `..`, `~`, etc. here like you can elsewhere.

### 3. Leave No Trace

Not all of this may be necessary, depending on how sensitive what you're doing is.

- You probably don't want to leave that token hanging around if you have no intentions of using it for some time, so go back to the [tokens page](https://github.com/settings/tokens) and hit the delete button next to it.
- If you don't need the repository again, delete it `rm -rf <folder>`.
- If do need the repository again, but don't need to automate it again, you can remove the remote by doing `git remote remove origin` or just remove the token by running `git remote set-url origin https://github.com/<username>/<repository.git>`.
- Clear your bash history to make sure the token doesn't stay logged there. There are many ways to do this, see [this question](https://askubuntu.com/q/903362/487048) and [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14750650/1021259). However, it may be easier to just prepend all the above commands with a space in order to prevent them being stored to begin with.

Note that I'm not a professional, so the above may not be secure in the sense that no trace would be left for any sort of forensic work.

Comment: `https://<token>@github.com` was not accepted with my portal, I had to use `https://oauth2:<token>@github.com`

Comment: @MushyPeas This answer using just `<token>` worked fine for me using a Personal Access Token.

Comment: > _However, it may be easier to just prepend all the above commands with a space in order to prevent them being stored to begin with._ <
That is not foolproof! Depending on the settings of `HISTCONTROL` even commands beginning with a space might be stored in the history. See also [this SO answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/483705/409795).

Answer (score 48):

**A 13 Aug 2021 post you must use**

- **Git Clone**

  `https://username:token@github.com/username/repository.git`

To generate a token:

*Settings* → *Developer settings* → *Personal access tokens* → *Generate new token**

- **Git Push**

After successful cloning, the *next* time when you do `git push`, you won't have to mention the username again. You can confirm this by opening the `.git/config` file in [Notepad](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Notepad). It will show:

```
[remote "origin"]
    url = https://username:tokenxxxxxxxxxx@github.com/username/repo.git
```

Comment: A token where? At GitHub? What page specifically? That information ought to be included in the answer (but *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** ***[without](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/131011)*** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** "Edit:", "Update:", or similar - the answer should appear as if it was written today).)

Answer (score 34):

Though there are many answers, I faced the repeated issue when username or password had special characters in them.

[URL encode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Percent-encoding) your username and password for Git, and then use it as part of URL itself (when there isn't any security concern).

Say, the URL encoded value of the username:

> 'user+1' is user%2B1

And the URL encoded value of the password:

> 'Welcome@1234' is Welcome%401234

Then your Git clone URL would look like,

`git clone https://user%2B1:Welcome%401234@actual-git-url-for-the-repo` works perfectly, whereas,

`git clone https://user+1:Welcome@1234@actual-git-url-for-the-repo` gives you 403 errors.

Just in case, if you want to URL encode online: *[URL Encode and Decode - Online](https://www.urlencoder.org/)*

Answer (score 22):

To clone a repository, first you should generate an access token (you can't use your login password anymore) and then clone the repository with this generated token.

##### Generate access token:

**GitHub:** 
*Settings* → *Developer settings* → *Personal access tokens* → *Generate new token*

**[Bitbucket](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bitbucket):** 
*Settings* → *Personal Bitbucket settings* → *App passwords* → *Create app password*

##### Clone the repository:

**GitHub:**

```
git clone https://YOUR-USERNAME:GENERATED-TOKEN@github.com/YOUR-USERNAME/YOUR-REPOSITORY
```

**Bitbucket:**

```
git clone https://YOUR-USERNAME@bitbucket.org/YOUR-REPOSITORY
```

It will prompt you for the generated token.

Answer (score 18):

I solved this problem in the following way:

[image]

Comment: never a good idea to type your password in command line. Did you know your system may store command line history in a file? (Ex: Linux has an hidden file named .bash_history)

Comment: Correct. Whenever I do this, or something like this, which at times can be very convenient, I always delete the command I used from the history (history -d).

Comment: @FrancescoMarchetti-Stasi you don't need to delete the command, just use a space at the beginning of the command and it will never get stored in the history.

Comment: Yes--I learnt it only a couple of months ago, after almost 30 years on Unix systems... shame on me :)

Comment: ...unless you are on a corporate server which stores commands you type even so. Passwords on the command line are never a good idea.

Comment: But the password will be still there in .git/config file. So it is not at all secure.

Comment: This ought to be [in text form](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/).

Answer (score 15):

**On Windows**, the following steps should retrigger the GitHub login window when `git clone`ing:

- Search start menu for "[Credential Manager](https://www.techradar.com/uk/news/what-is-windows-credential-manager)"
- Select "Windows Credentials"
- Delete any credentials related to Git or GitHub

[image: Result]

Answer (score 12):

If you're using `http/https` and you're looking to **FULLY AUTOMATE** the process without requiring any user input or any user prompt at all (for example: inside a CI/CD pipeline), you may use the following approach leveraging `git credential.helper`

```sh
GIT_CREDS_PATH="/my/random/path/to/a/git/creds/file"
# Or you may choose to not specify GIT_CREDS_PATH at all.
# See https://git-scm.com/docs/git-credential-store#FILES for the defaults used

git config --global credential.helper "store --file ${GIT_CREDS_PATH}"
echo "https://alice:${ALICE_GITHUB_PASSWORD}@github.com" > ${GIT_CREDS_PATH}
```

where you may choose to set the `ALICE_GITHUB_PASSWORD` environment variable from a previous shell command or from your pipeline config etc.

Remember that "store" based git-credential-helper stores passwords & values in plain-text. So make sure your token/password has very limited permissions.

---

Now simply use https://alice@github.com/my_repo.git wherever your automated system needs to fetch the repo - it will use the credentials for `alice` in `github.com` as store by git-credential-helper.

Answer (score 11):

I prefer to use [GIT_ASKPASS](https://git-scm.com/docs/gitcredentials) environment for providing HTTPS credentials to Git. 
Provided that login and password are exported in `USR` and `PSW` variables, the following script does not leave traces of password in history and disk, plus it is not vulnerable to special characters in the password:

```bash
GIT_ASKPASS=$(mktemp) && chmod a+rx $GIT_ASKPASS && export GIT_ASKPASS

cat > $GIT_ASKPASS <<'EOF'
#!/bin/sh
exec echo "$PSW"
EOF

git clone https://${USR}@example.com/repo.git
```

**NB**: Note the single quotes around the [heredoc](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Here_document) marker `'EOF'` which means that temporary script holds literally `$PSW` characters, not the password / expanded value of `PSW` variable

Comment: if you escape dollar sign - `\$PSW` you'll avoid unnecessarily embedding password into temporary file

Comment: @Marcin that's exactly what my recipe is avoiding: the temporary file referred  in GIT_ASKPASS holds just the name of PSW variable,  not its value

Comment: The $PSW in <<EOT is interpolated before file is created unless you escape dollar sign

Comment: @MarcinWisnicki Please tell the name and version of your shell. It works perfectly in Ubuntu Dash (/bin/sh) 0.5.11 and Bash 5.1.8 (but is expected to work in earlier versions of both as well).  Please check if you put single quotes around `EOF` in `cat >$GIT_ASKPASS <<'EOF'` as provided in the listing

Comment: thanks, the qoutes around EOF made all the difference!

Answer (score 5):

Use:

```
git config --global core.askpass
```

Run this first before cloning the same way, and it should be fixed!

Comment: Setting **global** configuration is never a good idea as it could mess up other clones.

Answer (score 3):

The organization that I work for uses Atlassian's [Bitbucket](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bitbucket) product (not GitHub), essentially their version of GitHub so that repositories can be secured completely on premise.  I was running into a similar problem as @coordinate, in that my password was required for a new repository I checked out.  My credentials had been saved globally for all Bitbucket projects, so I'm not sure what prompted the loss of credentials.

In short, I was able to enter the following Git command (supplying *only* my username), which then prompted Git's Credential Manager to prompt me for the password, which I was then able to save.

```
git clone https://user@code.domain.org/git/[organization]/[team]/[repository.git]
```

*Note: the bracketed directory sub-paths simply refer to internal references, and will vary for you!*

Answer (score 2):

### HTTPS Git URLs

```
git clone https://user:password@host
```

Including the password in the Git URL is [considered bad practice](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-config#Documentation/git-config.txt-transfercredentialsInUrl) because it risks inadvertent credentials exposure in config files and command history. It also breaks if the password changes.

**More secure and more reliable is to use a credential-generating helper such as [Git Credential Manager](https://github.com/git-ecosystem/git-credential-manager)** (included in Git for Windows) **or [git-credential-oauth](https://github.com/hickford/git-credential-oauth)** (included in several Linux distributions).

> The first time you authenticate, the helper opens a browser window to the host. Subsequent authentication within storage lifetime is non interactive.

### SSH Git URLs

SSH authentication requires an SSH key. This file is thousands of bytes; you can't include it in the URL. You can include the username in the URL:

```
git clone ssh://user@host
```

If the SSH key is protected by a passphrase, [you can use ssh-agent to remember it](https://docs.github.com/en/authentication/connecting-to-github-with-ssh/generating-a-new-ssh-key-and-adding-it-to-the-ssh-agent#adding-your-ssh-key-to-the-ssh-agent).

Answer (score 2):

## Git Custom Helper Script at Clone Time:

***Using Only Environment Variables***

### tl;dr

***One-liner***

```bash
git -c credential.username=${CI_GIT_USER} -c credential.helper='!f() { test \"$1\" = get && echo "password=${CI_GIT_PASSWORD}"; }; f' clone --branch $CI_GIT_BRANCH $CI_GIT_URL $CI_GIT_ROOT
```

***Multi-liner***

```bash
git -c credential.username=${CI_GIT_USER} \
    -c credential.helper='!f() { test \"$1\" = get && echo "password=${CI_GIT_PASSWORD}"; }; f' \
    clone --branch $CI_GIT_BRANCH $CI_GIT_URL $CI_GIT_ROOT
```

### Custom `git credential.helper` scripts

From the `git credentials` docs:

https://git-scm.com/docs/gitcredentials#_custom_helpers

```ini
# or you can specify your own shell snippet
[credential "https://example.com"]
    username = your_user
    helper = "!f() { test \"$1\" = get && echo \"password=$(cat $HOME/.secret)\"; }; f"
```

Not great since it is loading from a file but this could interpolate an environment variable.

### Git Config at Clone Time

A little known fact is specifying git config when the git repo is not even created yet eg, cloning. You can specify `git -c key=value clone <git_url_here>`

I know this because I have had to get [git to accept self-signed certificate authorities](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11621768/how-can-i-make-git-accept-a-self-signed-certificate/41253757#41253757) at clone time for server and client challenges.

https://git-scm.com/docs/git#Documentation/git.txt--cltnamegtltvaluegt

### Why does the custom script work?

A `git credential.helper` needs to responds to either `get`, `store` or `erase` commands and reads from the `stdout` stream.

```bash
!f() { test \"$1\" = get && echo \"password=${CI_GIT_PASSWORD}\"; }; f
```

- `test \"$1\" = get` this checks if the command was `get`
- `&&` control operator will only run the next command if the prior command had an exit status that is *Truthy* (which weirdly has to be zero because that means `EXIT_SUCCESS`), a non-zero exit code is *Falsey* (Usually some failure code).
- `echo \"password=${CI_GIT_PASSWORD}\";` the `stdout` stream has a `key=value` response.
- `!f() { ... }; f` This whole outside wrapper defines the command and runs it.

https://git-scm.com/docs/gitcredentials#Documentation/gitcredentials.txt-codegetcode

### Resources

- https://git-scm.com/docs/gitcredentials#_custom_helpers
- https://git-scm.com/docs/git#Documentation/git.txt--cltnamegtltvaluegt
- https://git-scm.com/docs/gitcredentials#Documentation/gitcredentials.txt-codegetcode
- [How can I make git accept a self signed certificate?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11621768/how-can-i-make-git-accept-a-self-signed-certificate/41253757#41253757)

Comment: This answer is much underappreciated!

Answer (score 1):

In case you have the credentials stored in any kind of credential-helper, but not configured the credential helper to be active globally, you can clone like this:

```
git clone https://git.example.com/ns/repo.git --config=credential.helper=store
```

This sets the credential-helper configuration locally (for the new repository only) before cloning.

Answer (score 0):

You need only no verify **ssl**:

```
git -c http.sslVerify=false clone https://github.com/organization/repo.git
```

Answer (score -1):

Most of the time this works well.

```
git clone https://username:password@github.com/username/repository.git
```

However, there is another scenario when someone invites you to their organization's repository. And let’s say this is how the repository URL will look like.

```
https://github.com/organization/repo.git
```

Now in this scenario, the following URL

> https://username:password@github.com/username/repository.git

will not work. You need to make some modifications to it in the following way.

```
https://username:password@github.com/organization/repository.git
```