# Git access to private repository using HTTPS

Tags: git, git-clone

Trying to clone a private repository I have access to using HTTPS protocol, as that is only allowed outgoing traffic.

git does not ask for passwords, just failed.

```
error: The requested URL returned error: 403 Forbidden while accessing https://github.com/blah/blahblah.git/info/refs
```

What am I missing ?

Comment: How did you clone the project?

Answer (score 93, accepted):

Did you try inserting the username (and optionally password) in the clone URL?

```
 git clone https://username@github.com/blah/blahblah.git
```

or if you accept the consequences of storing your password in plain view:

```
 git clone https://username:password@github.com/blah/blahblah.git
```

See this thread with a lot of good info:

[How to provide username and password when run "git clone git@remote.git"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10054318/how-to-give-username-and-password-when-do-git-clone-gitremote-git)

EDIT: My original answer was just a quick fix, without understanding the full history of the asker, and it also works unattended, but for best security practices its better to let Git store your password. See @phpguru's answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/29018371/257090 as well.

Comment: Thanks, I assumed that git will ask for username and password but looks like I was wrong.

Comment: It's worth noting that if you have 2FA enabled, this will not work.

Comment: Note: I needed to generate a new PAT. I used the first option

Answer (score 40):

The answer by @mrjoltcola should work, but if you would prefer not to place your github password in your server's bash_history in plaintext on the command line then you can omit the password and be prompted for it:

```
git clone https://username@github.com/organizationname/reponame.git
Password:
```

I like that better.

Comment: This is the way to do it.

Answer (score 6):

If you are using two-factor authentication, you go to this link first:

> https://github.com/settings/tokens

Create a token, and then use it as the password:

```
git clone https://username:token@github.com/blah/blahblah.git
```

Answer (score 2):

While I was using HTTPS connections to **AWS CodeCommit repositories** on Linux, macOS, or Unix I got the same error.

I needed to enable the Git credential UseHttpPath by using below command.
**git config --global credential.UseHttpPath true**

Answer (score 0):

Github [no longer permit password authentication over https](https://github.blog/2020-12-15-token-authentication-requirements-for-git-operations/): you need to [use a personal access token instead](https://docs.github.com/en/github/authenticating-to-github/keeping-your-account-and-data-secure/creating-a-personal-access-token).

```
git clone https://<your_token>@github.com/<username>/<repo_name>.git
```

Answer (score 0):

If you try logging in with a new account,  you may still encounter authentication failures after creating a new token. You need device activation to remember your credentials. There are two ways, but I highly recommend **GitHub CLI**.

**Just follow the steps in GitHub Docs below.**

https://docs.github.com/en/get-started/getting-started-with-git/caching-your-github-credentials-in-git

After entering the code displayed on your device to activate the device, I can use the git clone immediately.