# Title: "GitHub 403 Error: Unable to Access Repository"

Tags: git, github

fatal: unable to access 'https://github.com/prempanchal206/Flipkart_Clone.git/': The requested URL returned error: 403

I've registered with the same ID as my global user, but the issue persists. I've also tried a few troubleshooting steps, but none of them seem to work. Can someone please help me understand why I'm getting this 403 error and how I can resolve it?

Here are the steps I've already tried:

- Checked my GitHub credentials, and they seem to be correct.
- Verified that my GitHub account has access to the repository.
- Tried cloning other repositories, and they work fine.

Any guidance or insights would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: What are you doing/trying to do what you get this error?

Comment: Thanks for looking into my issue. I'm encountering a 403 error when trying to clone the repository "https://github.com/prempanchal206/repo_name/". The exact error message I'm getting is: fatal: unable to access 'https://github.com/prempanchal206/repo_name/': The requested URL returned an error: 403.

Comment: Worth looking at similar questions such as: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24008982/git-access-to-private-repository-using-https

Comment: I don't know if removing the trailing slash would make any difference (so just end with .git)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Github has changes it's authentication method from password to SSH key from August 13, 2021. So You have to generate a SSH key and authenticate it to the your github account, that will allow you to perform any kind of actions.

Follow the instruction to generate SSH key : [Generate SSH key](https://docs.github.com/en/authentication/connecting-to-github-with-ssh/generating-a-new-ssh-key-and-adding-it-to-the-ssh-agent)

Add SSH key to the github account : [Add to the github](https://docs.github.com/en/authentication/connecting-to-github-with-ssh/adding-a-new-ssh-key-to-your-github-account)

This steps should resolve your query!