# Integrate TFS GIT repository to CruiseControl.Net

Tags: git, tfs, cruisecontrol.net

Latest Cruise Control build support "tfs" and "git" types in its  section.
Which one to use for getting source from "git" repository located at TeamFoundationService?

- TFS option has options to specify username and password to be able to login to the repository, but does not have branch option. (http://cruisecontrolnet.org/projects/ccnet/wiki/Team_Foundation_Server_(Tfs))
- GIT option have no password (http://cruisecontrolnet.org/projects/ccnet/wiki/Git)

What whould  section configururation would look like?

Comment: You must use the Git section. Have you tried setting the credentials in the repository uri? Like described here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10054318/how-to-provide-username-and-password-when-run-git-clone-gitremote-git

Comment: works! have also found the following...
If your repository is hosted on Visual Studio Online, you must enable basic authentication before you can use the command prompt to perform Git tasks. You can set this up from your User Profile in TFS. see here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd286572.aspx

Answer (score 2):

When you're connecting to a Git repository, you should use the Git option in CruiseControl .NET. The TFS option is only used when connecting to [tfvc](/questions/tagged/tfvc).

You can [specify a password in the Git Repository URL as described in this other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10054318/how-to-provide-username-and-password-when-run-git-clone-gitremote-git).

And remember to turn on Basic Authentication for your VSO account. [which is described here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd286572.aspx).