# unable to import remote git repository

Tags: git, egit

I am a rookie trying to set up a work flow with Github via egit.

I have a forked repository and I was trying to import a github repo using the CloneURI call from eclipse/Import.

> URI:       git://github.com/xxxxx/pyfunds.git
>   host:     github.com
>   repopath: /xxxxxx/pyfunds.git
>   protocol: git   Port:
>   blank ( i
>   tried with 9418 too)

Authentication block is now opaque and I can't enter my github creds. On hitting next, I see an error message:

> An error occured while trying to contact git://github.com/xxxxxx/pyfunds.git with possible reasons being Incorrect URL or No network connection.

How can I get around this. I am behind a firewall and I have set the http and https proxy as per my firm's proxy settings.

Comment: HAve you looked at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10054318/how-to-provide-username-and-password-when-run-git-clone-gitremote-git ?

Answer (score 1):

git:// URLs use the git-daemon native transport, which is it's own protocol, not HTTP. So it doesn't go through your configured HTTP proxy. Use an https:// URL to github instead.

Comment: When I use the github url path https://github.com/xxx/888.git and the connection protocol i set to https immediately I see at the top   "Internal Error;consult Eclipse error log"...

Comment: If you are using eclipse, just change from http to git in the protocol section when you are cloning your git repository using the git built in tool.