# Providing username with email when using Git clone

Tags: git, authentication, ssh

I'd like to clone a repository that uses ssh. To do that I need to enter my username. I've tried to do this based on [How to provide username and password when run "git clone git@remote.git"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10054318/how-to-provide-username-and-password-when-run-git-clone-gitremote-git). However, my username has @ in it, which seems to mess with the command.

My current command without username entered is `sudo git clone ssh://git@git.x/y/`. Now I want to do the same, but with my username abc@gmail.com. How do I do that?

If I try to write `sudo git clone abc@gmail.com@git.x/y/` I get the error `repository abc@gmail.com@git.x/y/ does not exist`

Answer (score 35, accepted):

Url-encode your username, replacing "@" with "%40".

Comment: Thanks. I now get an error msg: `gnutls_handshake() warning: The server name sent was not recognized`. I don't know if it's related to this or a separate issue. I can only change things on the client-side.

Comment: I believe that's a TLS validation issue. Searching for that error string leads to several suggested server configuration changes