# Git remote url with username in form of email address

Tags: git

I would like to have my git username saved in remote url address in order not to type it every time I push or pull.

I found many answers ([such as this one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10054470/1364327)) which solves the problem. The thing is that my username contains `@` since it is (and unfortunatelly must be) an email address.

When I enter `http://me@domain.com@myrepo.git`, the parser is confused and takes only `me` as the username.

How can I solve it? Is it even posisble? Unfortunatelly, I can't use ssh, to https is the only option.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Escape @ character in git proxy password](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6172719/escape-character-in-git-proxy-password)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Providing username with email when using Git clone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29356020/providing-username-with-email-when-using-git-clone)

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Use url-escaping, i.e. replace `@` in the username with `%40`:

```
http://me%40domain.com@myrepo.git
```

Comment: I can't get this working on AWS CodeCommit, I get a 403 error