# Invalid authentification with git clone

Tags: git, github, clone, credentials

I'm trying to clone a private repo that is not on my github account, but I do have access to. 
The commands I have used is

```
 git clone https://username:passwordgit@github.com/path/to/repo.git
 git clone https://username:password@github.com/path/to/repo.git
```

I get invalid username or password, but if I do

```
git clone https://github.com/path/to/repo.git
```

And enter the same username and password it works fine. What is the correct syntax?

Comment: maybe github team have deactivated that for security reasons.

Comment: hi @OSryx did you use to be able to do this and now can't?

Comment: git clone https://username:password@github.com/path/to/repo.git is a correct syntax. Just tried. Worked for me. Maybe you are entering wrong credentials.

you may refer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10054318/how-to-provide-username-and-password-when-run-git-clone-gitremote-git

Comment: @PankajSinghal, does it work for you when you are not an owner of the repo? because what i enter when prompted is exactly what I put in the syntax

Comment: @Angie If you say :P

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
git clone https://username:password@github.com/path/to/repo.git
```

This is the correct syntax. Maybe you are entering wrong credentials. you may refer to this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10054318/how-to-provide-username-and-password-when-run-git-clone-gitremote-git) here.