# Github password has @: Could not resolve host error

Tags: git, github

My github password includes `@` character. In doing git clone, I am getting an error message `could not resolve host: my@github.com` considering my password is "pass@my". Using backslash too presents the same error.

I am typing:

```
git clone myusername:pass@my@github.com/myusername/myrepo.git D:/myworkspace
```

How to resolve this?

Comment: Can you use an SSH key instead of a password?

Comment: How are you cloning this?

Comment: @ChrisMartin Thanks for your time but maybe you could elaborate/guide, as I am not very familiar with the process.

Comment: @mirror [GitHub's docs](https://help.github.com/categories/ssh/) do a better job than I could.

Comment: @Makoto Using git clone command from Windows cmd

Comment: What exactly are you typing?  Feel free to omit concrete details like your password and username...

Comment: @Makoto This: git clone https://myusername:pass@my@github.com/myusername/myrepo.git D:/myworkspace
And as an answer below suggests, URL encoding does the job. But, you can sure teach me anything!

Comment: Why aren't you able to use the conventional way:  `git://git@github.com:myusername/myrepo.git` ?  Failing *that*, why not try it through HTTPS?  `https://github.com/myusername/repo.git`.  You shouldn't be required to enter your password to *clone* the repository.

Comment: @Makoto Didn't know that, thanks! Found this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10054318/how-to-provide-username-and-password-when-run-git-clone-gitremote-git

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try URL-encoding it: `pass%40my`