# Personal URL to git repo Bonobo GIT server

Tags: git, bonobo

I have one little question.

What is Personal URL in Bonobo GIT server? What I can do with it or for what it is used?

Answer (score 2):

It's a URL which contains your username - this can be useful if you have multiple accounts you need to log into a server with - the URLs can then distinguish between them.

It's not really a Bonobo-specific feature - see the answers to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10054318/how-to-provide-username-and-password-when-run-git-clone-gitremote-git)  for example.