# How to automatically input a password in command line using batch file?

Tags: git, batch-file

I am making a batch file that automatically clone our repository, but it will ask for a password input before it can proceed. What i want is that i'll just hard code (or if there is another way) my password. and if it prompts/ask a password, it will automatically input the password i specified in my code... base on my little research (coz most of them are just the same solution)...

i got a code like this

```
@echo off

echo <password>| git clone <repository url> <output path>

pause
```

but it doesnt seem to do the trick.

can anyone help me? please???

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to provide username and password when run "git clone git@remote.git"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10054318/how-to-provide-username-and-password-when-run-git-clone-gitremote-git)

Answer (score 2):

You can simply use the `user:password` in the clone URL (`http://user:password@myserver.com/repo.git`)

Or you can use `GIT_ASKPASS`, so in your batch file:

- create another batch file that do the echo
- set the environment variable `GIT_ASKPASS` to the path to the echo batch file
- call git
- remove the echo batch file

In a windows batch file it could be something like that (inspired from [jenkins-git-client](https://github.com/jenkinsci/git-client-plugin/blob/git-client-2.4.6/src/main/java/org/jenkinsci/plugins/gitclient/CliGitAPIImpl.java#L1693)):

```
@echo off

REM Create askpass batch
>askpass.bat  echo @set arg=%%~1
>>askpass.bat echo @if (%%arg:~0,8%%)==(Username) echo USERNAME
>>askpass.bat echo @if (%%arg:~0,8%%)==(Password) echo PASSWORD
set GIT_ASKPASS=%cd%\askpass.bat

REM Clone
git clone <repository url> <output path>

REM Remove askpass batch
del askpass.bat
```

Not sure if git will accept a batch file as ASKPASS or if you have to use a shell script, but I hope you get the idea.

Comment: Updated again, should work better. I'm not good in windows batch files.

Comment: still doesnt work for me

    < -- (@)set arg=
    (@)if (~0,8 ) echo hots -->

is this supposed to be the output..

Comment: Still Not Working :(

Comment: Try to add debug output (`>>askpass.bat echo @echo %%arg%% ^>^&2`) after the first `>askpass.bat` line. Then provide the output you get.

Comment: ill answer this later.. there is an issue here.. not related to this problem though.. but related to the repository