# How to troubleshoot a url error with "Port number ended with 'y'"?

Tags: git, gitlab, git-clone

While trying to clone an already existing repository from gitlab into my local drive. I used the format

```
$ git clone https://github.com/libgit2/libgit2  mylibgit
```

The resulting folder e.g `mylibgit` was found somewhere outside the XAMPP web folder (i.e htdocs), I moved it there but it's not working as supposed.

I moved it out to my desktop and got the error :

```
fatal: unable to access 'https://git@gitlab.com:xxxxx/yyyyyy/':Port number ended with 'y'
```

Comment: You're mixing SSH urls with https.

Comment: Maybe this article help: https://stackoverflow.com/a/10054470/4573839

Comment: use `git clone git@gitlab.com:libgit2/libgit2.git`

Answer (score 10):

For gitlab, you don't need to specify the user.
Replace it by an https url based on your GitLab account name.

```
cd /path/to/your/repo
git remote set-url origin https://gitlab.com/<username>/<yourProjectName.git>
git push -u origin master
```

Note:

> trying to clone an already existing repository from gitla

This contradict "`git clone https://github.com/libgit2/libgit2`", since this is a GitHub url, not a GitLab one.

Comment: @Madeo What does `git remote -v` return? You would see '`origin`' if you have cloned a repository. But for a new local repository, you would need to add a remote.

Comment: @Madeo `cd /path/to/local/new/repo; git remote add oprigin https://gitlab.com/<aproject>/<arepo>`: make sure `<aproject>/<arepo>` on GitLab is anew empty repository (no README, no nothing)

Comment: @Madeo I would need to see the URL used to understand. There is no port number involved.

Comment: @Madeo `git remote add` works perfectly in an initialized repo, with HTTPS or SSH URLs. You simply used an incorrect URL triggering that "Port number" error message.

Comment: @Madeo I did not express an opinion when stating "`git remote add works perfectly in an initialized repo, with HTTPS or SSH URLs`. I was stating a fact, a practice seen many times over the years, including in official documentations: https://help.github.com/en/github/importing-your-projects-to-github/adding-an-existing-project-to-github-using-the-command-line

Comment: @Madeo So I would be genuinely interested to know what URL did you use which could possibly trigger `Port number ended with 'c'`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/213863/discussion-between-vonc-and-madeo).

Answer (score 4):

Gitlab actually requires a user when using deploy tokens. For me, this was caused by mixing in ssh syntax as `http://<user>:<pass>@gitlab.com:repo` instead of `gitlab.com/repo`.

Answer (score 2):

if you change your remote from using ssh to https and accidentally leave a colon in the string - you will a message like this. It's a confusing message, but it makes sense once you understand the source of the problem.

Answer (score 1):

I had similar problem. Just corrected(removed git@ and port number) URL in .git/config file and it worked.

[remote "origin"]
    url = https://git@gitlab.com**:xxxxx**/yyyyyy/

To

[remote "origin"]
    url = https://gitlab.com/yyyyyy/

Answer (score 0):

I later found the problem, I was not typing  `cd /path/to/your/repo` at the beginning.

I was actually typing `gitlab` instead of `Github`.

Thanks.

Comment: As a new user, my votes don't count, yet. So, "thanks" is still the word.

Answer (score 0):

This may be useful for someone, in my case I just had a wrong URL with `:` instead of `@` before the Gitlab URL:

```
https://user:token:gitlab.com/repo.git
```

should be

```
https://user:token@gitlab.com/repo.git
```

I know it's obvious but it's just worth double-checking the format :D