# Bitbucket clone: Port number ended with 'T'

Tags: git, jenkins, bitbucket

I try to make a clone (mirror) of my bitbucket repo using jenkins execute shell (not the git plugin).

My credentials:

```
username
passwd
```

are saved in a variable: `myuser`
The credentials are right. We used [this plugin](https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Credentials+Binding+Plugin) to save the credentials. We're doing exactly the same for some other repo's (on our local git, not bitbucket) and it's working very good.

Now I try:

```
git clone --mirror https://${myuser}@bitbucket.org/team/repo.git
```

The error I'm facing is:

```
fatal: unable to access 'https://****@bitbucket.org/team/repo.git/': Port number ended with 'T'
```

Comment: Have a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45385673/how-to-troubleshoot-an-url-error-with-port-number-ended-with-y). You're mixing SSH urls with https.

Comment: @AndrejsCainikovs I saw that issue too but I don't see what I'm mixing up. I checked here too https://confluence.atlassian.com/bitbucket/clone-a-repository-223217891.html

Comment: Are you routing through a proxy?

Answer (score 5):

Was just banging by head around with a similar problem (attempt to clone from Gerrit over HTTPS with random HTTP password generated by Gerrit UI, URL in the form of `https://<username>:<password>@<gerrit.repo.url>` and getting 'Port Number ended with...' error), and it appears that the password must be **properly url-quoted**.

Realized that after trying to set git-credentials with 'store' helper and peeking at the file it created :-)

Comment: I have found @ and # in passwords to be causing this problem so far

Answer (score 4):

We need to encode the URL while passing special characters in the usernames or passwords with http or https protocol. For example if you want to use **user#1** in password and want to use it in URL you need to encode the **#** using **%23** and the password becomes **user%231**.

Reference: https://github.com/curl/curl/issues/1909#issuecomment-331565533

Answer (score 0):

For me also git clone was not working. But after adding proper git remote origin it worked.

```
Step 1. mkdir /local/repo/dir && cd /local/repo/dir
Step 2. git init
Step 3. git remote add origin https://<username>@bitbucket.org/<orgName>/<reponame>.git
```

Now git pull works without any issue

Answer (score 0):

Adding personal token resolved problem.
Go to your account - personal access tokens, create token and use it instead of password.

```
git clone https://username:token@bitbucket.org/.../repo.git
```