# Setup GitLab.com with 2FA

Tags: git, gitlab

I've recently added Two-Factor Authentification to my GitLab account. To push to my project, GitLab asked me to create an access token. After creating this token, I supplied it to my `.git/config` like so:

```
[remote "origin"]
    url = https://oauth2:ACCESS_TOKEN@gitlab.com/yourself/yourproject.git
```

Then I get the following error: **Port number ended with 'P'**, how is my syntax wrong?

Edit: I don't have any # or @ in my password so I shouldn't have to encode this character.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Bitbucket clone: Port number ended with 'T'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47076616/bitbucket-clone-port-number-ended-with-t)

Comment: `@` and `#` are not the only characters that require quoting. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Percent-encoding and http://www.blooberry.com/indexdot/html/topics/urlencoding.htm for instance (or just search for "url quoting").