# Is there a way to clone from gitlab with username and passwordr in one command?

Tags: git, bash, gitlab, git-bash

This solution from this post does not work [How to provide username and password when run "git clone git@remote.git"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10054318/how-to-provide-username-and-password-when-run-git-clone-gitremote-git)

```
git clone https://username:password@github.com/username/repository.git
```

fatal: unable to access 'http:/..: Could not resolve host: username

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Gitlab doesn't support cloning with http in one line. Maybe you can do it with ssh?

There are a few git services that do work with http cloning in one line. For example Github and Gitorious.
I think that Gitlab only supports a username prefix. The password always will be asked. Which also brings in a huge security advantage because in this way, your password never is stored in the logfiles.

Comment: Thank you for the detailed answer

Answer (score 10):

Yes, you can. The syntax is:

```
git clone https://username:token@gitlab.com/user/repo.git
```

Where `username` is your Gitlab username and `token` is generated through your gitlab's **settings > Access Tokens**