# Bash Script git clone credential prompt

Tags: git, bash, github, expect, git-clone

I'm trying to git clone a remote repository by using a simple bash script, but I could not get pass the prompt where github asks for my username and password. 
Here is my condensed version of the script:

```
#!/bin/bash
REPO=$1
USERNAME=$2
PASSWORD=$3
git clone $REPO
expect "Username for 'https://github.com':"
send $USERNAME
```

The send command does not seem like it is passing the USERNAME variable because the prompt never get pass the "Username for 'https://github.com':"

I tried piping and heredoc methods without any luck. 
Any help is gladly appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: You could avoid using `expect` and form the command to be executed with the username and password...  As seen here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10054318/how-to-provide-username-and-password-when-run-git-clone-gitremote-git

Comment: Thanks a bunch! will try this out.

Comment: It works with one caveat, urlencode any special characters in the password.

Comment: why not save your ssh key in github and clone repos without having to pass credentials?

Comment: I may not be the only one to use this script.

Answer (score 0):

You can include credentials in the `git push` command like so:
`git push https://<USER>:<PASS>@github.com/asdf/blah.git`
I hope this helps; let me know if this doesn't work.
jBit