# terraform-providers authorization failure

Tags: git

Following the directions here:
https://github.com/terraform-providers/terraform-provider-aws
under "Building Provider" I get an authorization error.

```
git clone --depth=1 git@github.com:terraform-providers/terraform-provider-aws
Cloning into 'terraform-provider-aws'...
Permission denied (publickey).
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.> 
Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
```

Suggestions?

Comment: Either add your SSH public key to your Github profile or use the HTTPS clone (`https://github.com/terraform-providers/terraform-provider-aws.git`)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to provide username and password when run "git clone git@remote.git"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10054318/how-to-provide-username-and-password-when-run-git-clone-gitremote-git)

Comment: Wouldn't call this a duplicate, as it is unnecessary to authenticate via SSH when cloning a public repo.

Answer (score 3):

You problem is not with the Terraform provider authorization, but rather with the Git access to github using SSH (as commented earlier). You might want to try HTTP for download, from the github portal, you can pick the SSH or HTTP download command from the "clone or download" button.