# Accessing a password-protected bitbucket with git

Tags: git, passwords, bitbucket

I have access to a bitbucket repository (not hosted by Atlassian, but inside our company). I can browse the web GUI manually just fine.

But when I do a `git clone`, then it redirects to the BitBucket login page and thus `git` gives up.

```
$ git clone https://xyz.abc.def/bitbucket/mystuff
Cloning into 'mystuff'...
fatal: unable to update url base from redirection:
  asked for: https://xyz.abc.def/bitbucket/mystuff/repos/mystuff/info/refs?service=git-upload-pack
  redirect: https://xyz.abc.def/bitbucket/login?next=/mystuff/repos/mystuff/info/refs?service=git-upload-pack
```

I am used to `git` prompting for a username/password, but for some reason it does not do that here. But then, I am normally using Gitlab or other repository software and am not familiar with BitBucket.

What is the way to make `git clone` and BitBucket work together?

I am using git 2.15.1 (Linux) and the BitBucket server is version 5.1.0.

Note that I can *not* use an Access Key (ssh key pair) for non-technical, organizational reasons outside of the scope of this question.

EDIT: adding the username inbetween (`https://myself@xyz.abc.def/...`) does not change the behaviour at all.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to provide username and password when run "git clone git@remote.git"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10054318/how-to-provide-username-and-password-when-run-git-clone-gitremote-git)

Comment: Well, close, @phd, but not the same. They are asking about the "ssh" access method; I am asking for https:// and also a bit specifically about BitBucket (the usual way https://user@... seems to be ignored by BitBucker...).

Comment: The accepted answer there shows how to do that for https URLs. Clearly dup.

Answer (score 0):

Use username in url

```
git clone http://<username>@<Bitbucket Server URL>/scm/<project key>/website.git
```

[bitbucketserver/clone-your-repository-and-manage-files-locally](https://confluence.atlassian.com/bitbucketserver/clone-your-repository-and-manage-files-locally-776798211.html)

[clone-a-repository](https://confluence.atlassian.com/bitbucket/clone-a-repository-223217891.html)

Comment: I tried that (sorry for not mentionining), but it does not change anything.