# Why am i not able to push files into My Git Repo

Tags: macos, github

I have this error.

remote: Permission to Karthik-B-06/react-starter.git denied to ArunTE.
fatal: unable to access 'https://github.com/Karthik-B-06/react-starter.git/': The requested URL returned error: 403

Comment: Hard to say without knowing what command you ran.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A 403 error ("Forbidden") likely means that you're not "allowed" to access the repository, likely because you aren't giving the correct credentials (you say you're trying to push to the repository; IIRC that does require credentials to do). Try some of the solutions in [this other StackOverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10054318/how-to-provide-username-and-password-when-run-git-clone-gitremote-git), providing your username and password, and see if they work.