# Authentication failed when cloning via script

Tags: git

I'm trying to build script which clone git repository without the need to enter the username and password.

I read this post:
[How to provide username and password when run “git clone git@remote.git”?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10054318/how-to-provide-username-and-password-when-run-git-clone-gitremote-git)

and try in that way:

```
git clone http://MyUserName:MyPassword@Location
```

But I'm getting the following error:
fatal: Authentication failed for `http://MyUserName:MyPassword@Location`

When I'm running the command without password:

```
 git clone http://MyUserName@Location
```

and enter the password in the next step, it works.

I want that it will be automatic without the need to enter the password.

what am I missing with the first command ?

Comment: Why don't you just store your password in the Git credential helper?

Comment: Do you have a special character in your password?

Comment: simple password: big letter, small letter and several digits

Comment: Why don't you use SSH instead of http?

Comment: can you reinstall the git without checking the Git credential manager,