# Can't clone git repo into my server machine "remote: HTTP Basic: Access denied"

Tags: git, clone

I'm trying to clone my repo into my production ubuntu server machine. When I clone it into my MacBook with https or with SSH everything is ok but when I try to clone it in my ubuntu server it says remote: `"HTTP Basic: Access denied"`. I saw many topics about it on stack overflow but none of the answer worked for me.

I precise it says `"remote: HTTP Basic: Access denied"` only when I use HTTPS. When I use SSH it freezes then its says 5 min later a time out message. Am I missing something? SSH keys missing? 2FA? why can I clone on my mac and not on my ubuntu server?

Comment: You need to add the SSH key from your server to your github account.

Comment: I did : I created an SSH key, i put on my server and I added it in the Settings of my gitlab project, but still does not work. How to tell git program on my server the path of the key pair i created ?

Comment: and I could still clone on my Macbook without any problem and without adding any ssh key to gitlab...

Comment: Are you cloning from the same account which you topk the SSH key from? I mean the key you need to add should be located under ’/home/<your_user>/.ssh’

Comment: I added the key pairs in another path. How can I tell git program the path of my key ?

Comment: The reason that you can clone without any key is perhaps because you have configured git user locally? What does ”git config —list user.email” show you?

Comment: "fatal: not in a git directory"

Comment: Try this one as well: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10054318/how-do-i-provide-a-username-and-password-when-running-git-clone-gitremote-git

Comment: Still same problem .. The answer in this post just gives a shortcut to provide username and password right in the URL. But in my case, they do ask me for mail/passwd but just after I provide they say “remote: HTTP Basic: Access denied”

Comment: well then it seems like your user/password is invalid :)

Comment: It is valid lol.. or maybe special chars used in my password are badly encoded and not interpreted by gitlab ....

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/193414/discussion-between-jerem-lachkar-and-cyclonecode).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems to be an authentication error. You must either check SSH keys or check user and password. Use these commands if you didn’t.

git confg --global user.name “your name”
git confg --global user.email “your email”

or

Make sure credentials are right. This command allows you to reenter the password.

git config --system --unset credential.helper