# How to request a password for GIT_REPOSITORY using HTTPS URL

Tags: cmake, external-project

The URL understood by the git command can be in the format HTTPS or SSH.

In CMake, using `ExternalProject_Add` for the specified `GIT_REPOSITORY` any URL understood by the git command may be used.

Using HTTPS user credentials must be given in order to "clone" a private repository. For `ExternalProject_Add`, such mechanism exists in the form of `HTTP_USERNAME` and `HTTP_PASSWORD` when using `DOWNLOAD_COMMAND`.

For `GIT_REPOSITORY` there doesn't seem to be such a method. When using:

```
include( ExternalProject )

ExternalProject_Add(test
    GIT_REPOSITORY git@github.com:myuser/myprivaterepo.git
    GIT_REMOTE_NAME origin
)
```

on a private repository the following error is given:

```
fatal: could not read Username for 'https://github.com': No such device or address
```

## Question

How can I make CMake request a password for `GIT_REPOSITORY` when using HTTPS connections to a private repository on `ExternalProject_Add`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While CMake doesn't provide explicit Git options for providing user credentials (like `HTTP_USERNAME` and `HTTP_PASSWORD`), you can manipulate the Git URL so that you are prompted for login password, as mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10054318/3987854). Just specify your `username` with a `@` in the URL:

```
ExternalProject_Add(test
    GIT_REPOSITORY https://username@github.com/myuser/myprivaterepo.git
    GIT_REMOTE_NAME origin
    USES_TERMINAL_DOWNLOAD ON 
)
```

Note, you may also need to enable the `USES_TERMINAL_DOWNLOAD` option to allow terminal input to enter your credentials. You could also provide your password directly in the URL itself, but best practices do not recommend this:

```
ExternalProject_Add(test
    GIT_REPOSITORY https://username:password@github.com/myuser/myprivaterepo.git
    GIT_REMOTE_NAME origin
    USES_TERMINAL_DOWNLOAD ON 
)
```

As a bonus, this will also work for Bitbucket accounts.