# Git Pull using http://username:password@server still asks for credentials?

Tags: git, powershell

I have the following script that loads credentials from a file and pulls using the credential-embedded URL format.

```
$remote = "http://server/repo.git"
$credential = Import-CliXml -Path 'gitcreds.xml'
Write-Host "Using credentials for $($credential.UserName)"
$url = $remote
$url = $url.Replace("http://","http://$($credential.UserName):$($credential.GetNetworkCredential().Password)@")
$url = $url.Replace("https://","https://$($credential.UserName):$($credential.GetNetworkCredential().Password)@")
Write-Host "Pulling from $($url)..."
git pull $url -f -q --progress --recurse-submodules
```

And I'm using this to generate the credential file:

```
$credname = Read-Host "Name for the credential file? (include .xml)"
$credential = Get-Credential
$credential | Export-CliXml -Path $credname
```

The debug line which outputs the updated `$url` looks exactly like I would expect (`Pulling from http://gituser:password@server/repo.git...`), but I'm still getting a Windows credential prompt.  Why is it happening and how can I avoid it?

Comment: I doubt `$($credential.GetNetworkCredential().Password)` is going to work on an object from `Import-CliXml`

Comment: Can u check if this is the issue https://stackoverflow.com/a/55721882

Comment: Or u can try somthing  like.  git config --global user.name "your username"

git config --global user.password "your password"

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen So I just went down the route of testing your doubt; it is incorrect.  The `pscredential` type exported/imported with `CliXml` *does* work and the methods remain intact.