# How do I get git clone from github to work without a username and password on Ubuntu?

Tags: github, ssh

On my macOS laptop I can do a git clone like so:

```
git clone https://github.com/my/repo
```

And it doesn't require a username and password.  My assumption is that this works because I have added my SSH key to github.

I have recently set up a new ubuntu machine, and I have generated a new SSH key and added it to github.  However whenever I try too clone a repository, it asks me for my github username and password.

I have even tried copying my SSH key and ~/.ssh/config from my other machine, and I still get the same result.

Is there something I am missing to make it work without a password?

Comment: Please [edit] your question to show the specific git command that you're running and the exact messages which it prints.

Answer (score 0):

The command you mention clones via HTTPS. To clone via SSH, use:

```
git clone git@github.com:my/repo.git
```

This command can also be copy pasted from the "Clone or download" option on your repository page and then selecting "Use SSH".

Comment: I am aware of this solution, but it won't work in my case.  I am trying to install a vim plugin, and the plugin manager chooses the git URL itself, and doesn't provide an opportunity to enter the credentials

Comment: @sak I am not aware of a workaround then, sorry. Perhaps you could take a look at [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10054318/5987698). Maybe your vim plugin manager expects the github repo to be public.

Comment: Thanks for the link and for your time!