# How to force git to prompt me for username + password on clone request

Tags: git, macos, github

I am being onboarded to a new team and have been made a **member** of their organization in GitHub, which (at least in the web UI) gives me full read access to their repos. So I try to clone one repo locally:

1. I go to the repo in GitHub and click the "**Clone or download**" link and select "*Clone with HTTPS*" (which is what I want)
2. I copy the clone URL to my clipboard
3. From a terminal I run `git clone https://github.com/<THEIR_ORG>/<THEIR_REPO>.git` (where the clone URL there is pasted from my clipboard, and I've verified several times it is correct). This is what I see:

```
$ git clone https://github.com/<THEIR_ORG>/<THEIR_REPO>.git
Cloning into '<THEIR_REPO>'...
remote: Repository not found.
fatal: repository 'https://github.com/<THEIR_ORG>/<THEIR_REPO>.git/' not found
```

This is a private repo under the organization. The curious thing is its not even prompting me for a username or password, which indicates to me that *somehow* I have my local git configured to automatically send a username which doesn't match a valid org/repo username and so its failing me automatically.

I have several GitHub accounts (for work + play) and I've used this laptop for all of them over the past several years.

So I ask: **why is git not prompting me for a username/password?** How can I force it to prompt me?

For the record I check my `~/.gitconfig` file and the contents are:

```
[core]
        excludesfile = /Users/myuser/.gitignore_global
[difftool "sourcetree"]
        cmd = opendiff \"$LOCAL\" \"$REMOTE\"
        path =
[mergetool "sourcetree"]
        cmd = /Applications/Sourcetree.app/Contents/Resources/opendiff-w.sh \"$LOCAL\" \"$REMOTE\" -ancestor \"$BASE\" -merge \"$MERGED\"
        trustExitCode = true
[user]
        name = My Name
        email = <MY_WORK_EMAIL_ASSOCIATED_WITH_THE_CORRECT_GH_ACCOUNT>
        username = <MY_WORK_USERNAME_ASSOCIATED_WITH_THE_SAME_GH_ACCOUNT>
        signingkey = <MY_GPG_SIGNING_KEY>
[commit]
        template = /Users/myuser/.stCommitMsg
        gpgsign = true
```

Also I had to enable 2FA for this organization, but I have generated my Personal Access Token and will use that (once prompted to do so) as the password instead of my normal GH password.

I think all I need to do is to *force* git to prompt me for credentials, and then I can send them and complete the clone request.

#### Update

I was thinking the OSX Keychain credential helper *might* be a factor here, so I tried running:

```
$ git credential-osxkeychain
usage: git credential-osxkeychain <get|store|erase>
```

So I then run the following commands (to disable the helper):

```
$ git config --local --unset credential.helper
fatal: --local can only be used inside a git repository

$ git config --global --unset credential.helper

$ git config --system --unset credential.helper
error: could not lock config file /etc/gitconfig: Permission denied

$ sudo git config --system --unset credential.helper
```

I restart the terminal and attempt the same clone again...but no dice.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I provide a username and password when running "git clone git@remote.git"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10054318/how-do-i-provide-a-username-and-password-when-running-git-clone-gitremote-git)

Comment: It's also worth noting that GitHub encourages using tokens. See [here](https://help.github.com/en/github/authenticating-to-github/creating-a-personal-access-token-for-the-command-line)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Pass the username in the URL:

```
git clone https://username@github.com/<THEIR_ORG>/<THEIR_REPO>.git
```

Comment: That works!!!! Any chance I could be so bold as to ask for an explanation as to why git wasn't prompting me for the username?! Thank you so much!

Comment: GitHub returns 404 (not found) when you're unauthorized, so you can't try to find private repos (I assume that's why). It doesn't return a 401 (not authorized), which would tell git to ask for credentials.