# Cannot git clone a repo while it does exist

Tags: git, github

I am trying to git clone a private repo, but it is returning

`repository not found`

I put the url in chrome and it does lead me to the repository. I tried to do

`git clone https://username@github.com/reponame`

which did not work either.

I have two different github accounts, and this is my first time using the other account for a new project. I wonder whether it has something to do with this.

Comment: But you do have access to the repo, right? Then I think you have to use the right credentials when you try to clone. I would try using ssh keys (and ssh url to the repo, of course).

Comment: It might be authentication issue.

Comment: Yes, I do have access to the repo and I suspect something goes wrong with authentication too. But I tired git clone ```https://username@github.com/reponmae``` and it still did not work.

Comment: Tried using SSH key and it did work. I wonder whether there is simpler ways to solve this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Considering you have two different GitHub accounts, you could place your username/password in the URL, e.g

`git clone https://username:password@github.com/username/repository.git`

Also, there is a huge discussion about it [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10054470/11644167).

> **NOTE**: If you are facing error because your password contains special characters, you could "encode" it.
>
> E.g. Let's assume your password is `password!` so, after encoding it will become `password%21`.
> You could do it in this website [url-encode-decode.com](https://www.url-encode-decode.com/)

Comment: Thank you for answering. I tried this method as well, my command reads: But my password contains a ```!```, and it seems that it cannot recognize that.

Comment: If your password contains special characters, you could encode it. I've update my answer and added the explanation on how to do it. Could you try it and let me know?

Answer (score 0):

This article can probably help you: https://help.github.com/en/github/creating-cloning-and-archiving-repositories/cloning-a-repository.

Looks like you have use this command:
`git clone https://github.com/YOUR-USERNAME/YOUR-REPOSITORY`