# php, shell and git clone

Tags: php, github

Here's possibility for cloning git private repository:

```
$ git clone https://github.com/username/repo.git
Username: your_username  #the username
Password: your_token  #the string that can be found by generating here https://github.com/settings/tokens
```

How to use in php

```
shell_exec("git clone https://github.com/username/repo.git");
```

with seting username and password?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you try

`shell_exec("git clone https://username:password@github.com/username/repo.git");`

[Source](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10054470/14648997)

Comment: It works only in own localhost, but not in a server.