# How to clone git repo using shell script with username and password

Tags: git, shell, github, sh

I need to clone git branch into my local directory using a shell script.

```
#!/bin/sh

echo $0
 
full_path=$(realpath $0)

dir_path=$(dirname $full_path)
 
root_dir=$(dirname $dir_path )

REPO_DIR="${root_dir}/utils"

username="test1"
password="testpass"

BRANCH_NAME="test-cd"

GIT_URL="https://wwwin-example.com/internal/demo.git"


GIT=`which git`

cd ${REPO_DIR}

${GIT} clone -b ${BRANCH_NAME} ${GIT_URL}
```

Here I am doing clone one branch my directory but here I need to use `username and password` along with the git command so that user will not provide it later. Once this script will run then the `git clone` command with *username and password* will fetch the branch to my local directory.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10054318/how-do-i-provide-a-username-and-password-when-running-git-clone-gitremote-git

Comment: @itachi, I have also checked this link. How I will add the `username and password` with URL dynamically. As I am new to bash script that is my concern only.

Answer (score 4):

> How I will add the username and password with URL dynamically

You can use your variables in `GIT_URL`:

```
GIT_URL="https://${username}:${password}@wwwin-example.com/internal/demo.git"
```