# Can't push from Git Bash: Could not find UI helper 'GitHub.UI'

Tags: git, git-credential-manager

After a fresh install, I could clone the repository, make changes and commits, but when I try to push I get the following warning:

> warning: could not find UI helper 'GitHub.UI'

After this, the process seems to still be running, but it gets stuck until I press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>C</kbd> it.

I couldn't find this error online.

I can push from [GitHub Desktop](https://desktop.github.com/).

Comment: Git itself has no occurrences of "UI helper" in the source code. Git *does* have *credential helpers* and perhaps you have one configured that, in turn, tries to run something called a "UI helper". The output of `git config --list --show-origin` might be helpful here.

Comment: Update: this appears to come from [git-credential-manager](https://github.com/GitCredentialManager/git-credential-manager).

Comment: [Git Bash](https://superuser.com/questions/1053633/what-is-git-bash-for-windows-anyway) presumably implies [Windows](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_Windows)(?). Shouldn't it have more tags?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Maybe, there is some kind of **issue** in the latest update of **Git v(2.39.0)**. However, you can get rid of this by installing the **previous version** of **Git v(2.38.1)**.

Follow these **few steps** to solve this issue:

1. Uninstall the currently installed Git.
2. Go to *[Git for Windows 2.38.1](https://github.com/git-for-windows/git/releases/tag/v2.38.1.windows.1)* to download the Git v(2.38.1)
3. Install the Git v(2.38.1)

**Done!**

Comment: This is the best and working answer!

Comment: as cem answered below v2.39.0(2) fixed the problem, no need to downgrade

Comment: @perimeno Yes, but there was no update available at that time.

Comment: This solved me on windows 11 22H2

Answer (score 19):

I have tried running the command in CMD, and it worked. Apparently it's because it can't show the options to authenticate.

Comment: I got the same message trying to clone a repository. I was going to take this suggestion, but because I'm trying to force myself to learn PowerShell I ended up trying from there. I got the same warning message, but instead of locking up (like it did in bash) I got a text menu of ways to authenticate with credentials manager. Using the default, "Web browser", with a browser already authenticated to my Github account worked perfectly.

Comment: I found that once I used CMD to authenticate to BitBucket, I could then use VS Code and Git BASH to commit, push, fetch, etc.

Answer (score 14):

They fixed the issue with the v2.39.0(2) update. Mine is solved with this version. Check [the patch notes](https://github.com/git-for-windows/git/releases/):

> The Git Credential Manager version shipped with Git for Windows v2.39.0 [could not always find its UI helper](https://github.com/git-for-windows/git/issues/4165) which was fixed by [upgrading to a fixed version](https://github.com/git-for-windows/git/issues/4166).

Answer (score 12):

I tried installing an older version (2.38.x) and it worked.

Comment: Seems like 2.39.0 has some issue

Comment: It worked on 2.38 perfectly after entering PAT (Personal Access Token).

Answer (score 7):

Actually the version 2.39 (released 3 days ago) is broken for [Atlassian](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bitbucket) too with this error *'could not find UI helper "Atlassian.Bitbucket.UI"'*, and you won't be able to download from [Visual Studio Code](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visual_Studio_Code) neither.

The only solution is download a previous version of Git, like 2.38.X.

Answer (score 6):

I installed GitHub Desktop, and it solved the problem.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 6):

Cloning from the project location, instead of git bash, gave me the below three options and after selecting PAT ([personal access token](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Personal_access_token)) and entering my PAT I was able to successfully clone my repository.

People, who don't know about PAT, can follow the below link.

[image]

[How to generate a personal access token](https://docs.github.com/en/enterprise-server@3.4/authentication/keeping-your-account-and-data-secure/creating-a-personal-access-token)

Comment: Thank you. It worked and completely fixed the issue without downgrading git.

Comment: Please review *[Why not upload images of code/errors when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/)* (e.g., *"Images should only be used to illustrate problems that* ***can't be made clear in any other way,*** *such as to provide screenshots of a user interface."*) and [do the right thing](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/74851019/edit) (it covers answers as well). Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 5):

I was trying to clone a repository; passing credentials in the clone URL solved the issue for me.

The [details are here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10054318/how-do-i-provide-a-username-and-password-when-running-git-clone-gitremote-git).

Answer (score 3):

I tried Git clone on a fresh installed Git Bash and was prompted with the same message. I guess it happens when trying to authenticate the user.

I resolved it by either using GitHub Desktop or installing older versions on Git Bash.

You can install older releases here: [Git for Windows](https://github.com/git-for-windows/git/releases/).

Answer (score 3):

I've also encountered a similar issue with Git for *2.39.0.windows.1*.

A Git *clone* from an Atlassian cloud-hosted Bitbucket repository gave me a

> warning: could not find UI helper 'Atlassian.Bitbucket.UI'

I uninstalled 2.39 and installed 2.38 with the links above and bam, Atlassian Bitbucket displays its *Connect to Bitbucket* login modal.

Answer (score 0):

Just delete Git from *Control Panel* and reinstall from the [Git scm website](https://git-scm.com/), and then push. It will ask for authentication. Provide Git the email address and password. Now it solved the problem.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: How exactly does one get to Control Panel? It is also one of the few cases where a screenshot would be appropriate. Please respond by [editing (changing) your answer](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/74798144/edit), not here in comments (********* ***without*** ********* "Edit:", "Update:", or similar - the answer should appear as if it was written today).

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the problem with the *git-credential-manager* which is installed along with the Git installation.

Uninstall Git, and then install again.

Select 'None' when "choose a credential Manager" screen to skip this issue.

[Choose None instead of Git Credential Manager](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sA67F.png)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -2):

Installing an old version worked for me, version Git-2.38.0-rc0-64-bit.exe to be specific.

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow! Great that you're looking to contribute by answering some questions. It seems, however, that your answer is a duplicate of already existing answers though. This is not really useful, so try to avoid this in the future.