# Blank screen for Git credential manager window in Visual studio 2022

Tags: git, visual-studio, visual-studio-2022, git-credential-manager

Team, we are currently using dev vm for our development. i am getting a blank screen for git credentials manager when trying to clone a solution inside visual studio 2022. i have tried updating VS to the latest version, restarting VM and restarting Visual studio, but none of them worked. this is how its showing. can someone help me with a fix?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Check first your Git version, since there is a (possibly related) [bug with Git for Windows 2.39](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74807684/6309).

GCM-Core is in the [process to being renamed GCM](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68768432/6309) (without core).
I know the last Git for Windows ships with both a `git-credential-manager-core.exe` and a `git-credential-manager.exe`, but there might be a side effect for Visual Studio.