# Can anyone solve this git and github problem?

Tags: git, github

When I try to push my code to an existing GitHub repo, it shows the below error:

Command:

```
git push
```

Result:

```
warning: could not find UI helper 'GitHub.UI'
Select an authentication method for 'https://github.com/':
  1. Web browser (default)
  2. Device code
  3. Personal access token
option (enter for default):
```

Which authentication method should I choose and how I push my GitHub repository?

Comment: Hi! Please add the details of your environment to your question. What happens when you press ENTER? From the first look, it seems like you haven't configured `git` on this machine.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/q/74778511/761095

Answer (score 1):

I assume that you are using Git for Windows client. In this case make sure that you are using the latest version. There was a relevant fix in [Git for Windows 2.39.0(2)](https://github.com/git-for-windows/git/releases/tag/v2.39.0.windows.2):

> The Git Credential Manager version shipped with Git for Windows
> v2.39.0 could not always find its UI helper which was fixed by
> upgrading to a fixed version.

And to answer your question:

> Which authentication method should I choose and how I push my GitHub
> repository?

Choose the default method "Web browser". Normally, a web browser should open GitHub and prompt you to authenticate the client. It's more convenient than having to generate and enter your personal access token (PAT).