# Python way to clone git repositories

Tags: python, git

How to parse the text file in python and read the lines which contains URLs of git repos without using any libraries?

**Note: The text file contains 10 URLs of git repositories.**

**Format of text file:**

```
repo_name https://www.github.com/path/to/repo
repo_name https://www.github.com/path/to/repo
repo_name https://www.github.com/path/to/repo
```

**Edit:** Got it sorted.

```
def main():
    # reading txt file
    opFile = open("testrepo/textfile.txt", "r")
    lines = opFile.readlines()
    opFile.close()

    for line in lines:
        line = line.strip()
        parts = line.split()
        repo_name = parts[0]
        branch = parts[1]
        git_url = parts[2]
        print("Repository name: {} \n Branch name: {} \n Git clone url: {}".format(repo_name, branch, git_url))

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

**Output:**

```
Repository name: repo_name
Branch name: master 
Git clone url: https://gitlab.com/path/to/repo.git
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Python way to clone a git repository](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2472552/python-way-to-clone-a-git-repository)

Comment: @ShanteshwarInde I don't want to use libraries. The text file contains 10 git repos url to clone. the only way is to parse the file but I don't know how to

Comment: Then please mention all things in question. how we come to know what you're looking for?

Comment: @ShanteshwarInde I have modified the question.

Comment: Did you try anything? Like select the appropriate strings with sth like `if 'www.github.com' in string:...`?

Comment: @MrFuppes No I have not tried this method but I think it wont work for multiple lines because 'www.github.com' would be common in each line.

Comment: ok, that wasn't clear in the former version of your question... also, the question is not really related to cloning git repos, as it stands, this is just about txt file parsing - in case you wonder where the dupe flags come from.

Comment: @MrFuppes It was. I had given the format of text file

Answer (score 0):

your file is just 2 part:

```
repo_name ==> [0]
https://www.github.com/path/to/repo ==> [1]
```

So you will give an error:

```py
IndexError: list index out of range
```

Comment: Actually I added branch name in my text file afterwards during testing.